# Concatenate results from SQL query base on another column

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM ( SELECT hostname, table2.user-id, table2.user-team from
 INNER JOIN table2 on table1.id = table2.id)
```

So at the moment my SQL query outputs this:

```
hostname user-id     user-team
a           1           alpha   
a           2            beta 
b           3            beta
c           4           alpha
c           1            null
c           3           alpha
```

but what I want is something like this:

```
hostname user-id     user-team
a           1, 2      alpha, beta   
b           3            beta
c           4, 1, 3     alpha
```

I'm trying to use a `GROUP BY hostname` statement at the end of my query, and a `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT user_id SEPARATOR  ', '),` `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT user_team SEPARATOR  ', '),`

But this then only returns the first hostname result and all the values possible for the user-id and team-id. I feel like I'm close, but I can't quite get it. Any help?

(At present it returns)

```
hostname    user-id      user-team
a            1,2,3,4       alpha, beta
```

with this as the SQL query

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM ( SELECT hostname, 
              GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT table2.user-id SEPARATOR(', '),
              GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT table2.team-id SEPARATOR(', ')
       from table1
       INNER JOIN table2 on table1.id = table2.id) 
GROUP BY hostname
```

Although the queries arean't 100% accurate, that is the logic in them (they just contain far more columns in the real world problem I have.)

Comment: can you post the whole query?

Comment: You don't need DISTINCT or a subquery for that

Comment: The query is actually more complex, it's just making it more complicated than necessary for the question. I just needed to show there was a subquery. Thanks for the input tho :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you miss the `GROUP BY`

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/670e8c/1)**

```
SELECT hostname,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT user_id SEPARATOR  ', ') as users, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT user_team SEPARATOR  ', ') as teams
FROM Table1
GROUP BY hostname
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| hostname |   users |       teams |
|----------|---------|-------------|
|        a |    1, 2 | alpha, beta |
|        b |       3 |        beta |
|        c | 4, 1, 3 |       alpha |
```

**EDIT:** After you edit your question, the problem was you put the `GROUP BY` outside of the subquery